# Как правильно сделать маршрут для нового бандла symfony?

Tags: symfony2

Не находит Route прописанный с помощью аннотаций , хотя debug:router показывает что такой путь есть.
Вот как прописан он в контроллере:

```
namespace Iphpsandbox\PhotoBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Iphpsandbox\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;



class PhotoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route ("/photos", name = "photos")
     */
```

Вот routing.yml :

```
iphpsandbox_photo:
    resource: '@IphpsandboxPhotoBundle/Controller/PhotoController.php'
    type: annotation
```

Подключено так же как и AppBundle, но почему-то symfony выдает

> No route found for "GET /photos/"

Comment: `GET /photos/` и `GET /photos` - разные маршруты(слеш на конце)

Comment: спасибо, я вводил /photos вот так, но роутер сам доставлял слеш, из-за того что есть еще один роутер определен как GET  /photos/g{id}

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Iphpsandbox\PhotoBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Iphpsandbox\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;



    class PhotoController extends Controller
    {

    /**
     * @Route("/photos{trailingSlash}", requirements={"trailingSlash" = "[/]{0,1}"}, defaults={"trailingSlash" = "/"})
     */
```